# how add an object in game view controller?

Tags: swift

```
@IBOutlet var green1: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var red1: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var blue1: UIImageView!









@IBAction func red(sender: UIButton) {



    green1.hidden = true
    red1.hidden = false

    blue1.hidden = true




}
```

I want to add and remove objects when the button is pressed.

At the moment they hide and are visible, but i want to remove them completely form the scene when the button is pressed.
And i want the one that is not hidden to appear.

i tried add child and subview but it didn't work the code is in GameViewController.

Answer (score 0):

If you are showing/hiding frequently, changing `hidden` property is ok, however if you want to remove completely you need to remove the particular image view from its super view.

ex - `green1.removeFromSuperView()` and when you need it, you have to add as subview and while adding provide its frame.

Comment: if the objects are hidden will they collide in a collision function ?

Comment: If you change frame and frames overlap each other then it may happen.

Comment: I have 3 different buttons and I want each one to add a certain object based on clouds and remove the other two objects. I did that for all of them I get a problem because I press a button it tries to remove an object that is not there and  and it doesn't add the new object.

Comment: Have a check before removing the object, because when you click a button for adding a view and removing other two, it does not mean that other two will always be there.

Comment: yeah but in the game the objects are overlapping so you can't check

Comment: Overlapping doesn't mean that its parent view will be changed. You are adding all three items at same position?

Comment: And you checking if there is come view before adding? lets discuss this in chat.